# asp .net web service issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a web service in Asp.net with C# and it gives the followoing error:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

The exception is as follows:

```
The Following Application Error Occurred. Error Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at DataProcessing.Class1.getData(String dbObjectName_SP_Querry, ObjectType dbObjectType, SqlDbType[] dbObjectDataType, String[] dbParamterName, String[] dbparameterValue, Int32[] dbParameterSize)
   at HAPS_BusinessLogic.EditMaster.edit(String sqlConnection, String PANUMBER, String PASUFFIX, String CLIENTFNAME, String CLIENTLNAME, String LEASETYPE, String AMOUNTTOPAY, String PMTFROMDATE, String PMTTODATE, String PymtToDateReasonCode, String OORID, String APTNO, String APTADDRESS, String APTBORO, String APTZIP, String LLDTIN, String LLDLEGALNAME, String LLDAPTNO, String LLDADDRESS, String LLDCITY, String LLDSTATE, String LLDZIP, String VendorChangeReasonCode, String MONTHLYRENT, String LEASEDATESTART, String LEASEDATEEND, String MONTHREMAIN, String BALANCEREMAIN, String CLIENTCONTRIBUTION, String LEASEDATESIGN, String DATESEND, String LEASEID, String CLIENTSSN, String PRGIND, String RECTYPE, String MonthlyCityShareOfRent, String MODBY, String MODDTE, String PAUSRCOMMENT, String PRID, String status) in C:\Documents and Settings\tveli3517\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\HAPS_Dev\HAPS_BusinessLogic\EditMaster.asmx.cs:line 33
```

Comment: Can you post the exception details? There is simply not enough information otherwise.

Comment: yes if I can run the web service and degug , in the webservice I ahve a call to my Stored proc and have tried running the SP seprately form sql server 2005 and it works fine...but if I call it form the web service it does nt work and gives the above exception ...and has no more details

Comment: There is no way to help you with just that information.

Comment: What happened when this exception occurred? Can you give us any relevant code?  Without that, all we know is that it isn't doing something you expect it to.

Comment: You have an exception in EditMaster.asmx.cs:line 33 .... Could you at least show us that line (and surrounding lines). And I guess it's a webservice class + method, so show us that part too, because i guess the exception is probably from the service.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the lack of details, but if you're *consuming* a web service and getting an Exception, you might try to catch a FaultException like so:

```
        try
        {
            var svcResponse = Service.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            var message = ex.CreateMessageFault();
            if (message.HasDetail) {} // handle error...
        }
```

Comment: Fault information requires a library??What is the library needed that I have to add

Comment: FaultException is in System.ServiceModel.